# When does a double integral represent a surface area, and when does it represent a volume?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

When does $\int_Af(x,y)dA$ represent a surface area geometrically, and when does it represent a volume?
In my lecture notes I'm told it represent the volume underneath the surface $z=f(x,y)$, but I've found examples online computing double integrals to find the surface area of a surface.
Thanks a bundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\iint_S f \operatorname d S$ is the Surface Integral of scalar field $f$ over surface $S$.

When the curve can be described by a parameterised vector $S: \vec r(s,t)$, we have

$$\iint_S f(\vec r(s,t))\operatorname d S = \iint_S f(\vec r(s,t))\begin{Vmatrix} \frac{\partial \vec r(s,t)}{\partial s}\times \frac{\partial \vec r(s,t)}{\partial t}\end{Vmatrix} \operatorname d s \operatorname d t$$

Note: the scalar field takes a three dimensional vector as its argument, not simply the curvilinear coordinates.

---

The surface area of the curve $\;\vec r=\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\\g(x,y)\end{bmatrix}$ projected above some section $T$ of the x,y plane we use:

$$\begin{align}
\iint_S \operatorname dS
 & = \iint_T \begin{Vmatrix}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\\g(x,y)\end{bmatrix}\times\dfrac{\partial\;}{\partial y}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\\g(x,y)\end{bmatrix}\end{Vmatrix}\operatorname d x \operatorname d y
\\[1ex]
& = \iint_T \begin{Vmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\\ g_x(x,y)\end{bmatrix}\times\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\\g_y(x,y)\end{bmatrix}\end{Vmatrix}\operatorname d x \operatorname d y
\\[1ex]
& = \iint_T \sqrt{g_x(x,y)^2 +g_y(x,y)^2 + 1}\operatorname d x \operatorname d y
\end{align}$$

Note: here we are using a unit scalar field $f = 1$.

---

To find the volume between a surface $z=g(x,y)$ and a section $T$ of the x,y plane, we just use:

$$\iint_T g(x,y) \operatorname d x \operatorname d y$$

Which is a totally different beast altogether.

Answer (score 2):

$\iint_A f(x,y)dA$ represents the volume underneath the surface $z=f(x,y)$. When $f(x,y)=1$ you get the area of $A$, which is the volume under the plane $z=1$ intersected with $A$. Note that $\iint_AdA$ represents a volume, and the value of this volume (the scalar part) is the area of $A$.

Comment: So what about the surface area?

Comment: @ThanksABundle That's different. Are you taking a calculus course or reading a book? Look for surface integrals. If you want I could show you the formula...

Comment: I would not use a $\int \int_A ... dA$ to indicate what is instead $\int \int ... dx~dy$ or $\int \int ... dr~d\theta$.

Comment: @Dillon it does, but when the surface is in $\mathbb R^2$ (a flat surface).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I prefer to use the double integral notation $\iint dA$, never $\iint dxdy$, but $\int\int dx dy$ which are iterated integrals from calculus in one-variable.

Comment: I'm at university taking a vector calculus course

Comment: @VladimirVargas:  Your notation is non-standard, as you can see here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I learnt it from stewart calculus. I like it because when you say $\iint dxdy$ you are including a coordinate system whereas $\iint dA$ is independent of any system. When you say $\int \int dx dy$ you think of doing first $\int dx$ and then if the result is some expression $b$ then you do the integral $\int b dy$. However $\iint dA$ is a compact notation for a limit, by Fubini's Theorem you can write that limit as the iterated integrals $\int \int dx dy$.

Comment: Why not use the standard $\int_A dA$?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I feel better writing the double integral. https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/multiple-integral-notation-or-abuse-of.570160/ It's just a matter of taste, I guess.